# Error compiling C++ program against GeoIP library

Tags: c++, qt, autoconf, automake, geoip

I'm trying to compile a simple program using the GeoIP2 lite API.  I've compiled the GeoIP Lite program and it created the library files.  The .la file is in /mydir/libmaxminddb-0.5.3/src

I modified my .pro file to include:

```
LIBS += /mydir/libmaxminddb-0.5.3 -lmaxminddb
```

but when I compile my project errors with "Cannot find -lmaxminddb"

Can someone tell me what's wrong?  I've tried changing directories, adding a "lib" prefix to the maxminddb, and more, but I can't figure it out.

(I'm trying to link against libmaxminddb.a which is pointed to by libmaxminddb.la)

Comment: Looks like an automake/autoconf question. Suggest adding those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found elsewhere that with Qt Creator you can right click the project and add an external library.  When I do so, I see the .pro file adds:

```
LIBS
INCLUDEPATH
DEPENDPATH
```

So that's what you need to add!

Answer (score 0):

I believe in `autoconf` and friends the `-l` flags go in the `LDFLAGS` variabe, not `LIBS`.

Comment: I tried moving the -lmaxminddb to an LDFLAGS += line but now I get tons of errors about not being able to find the functions...I think this is taking me further from the right answers.

Answer (score -1):

That should be `LIBS += -L/mydir/libmaxminddb-0.5.3 -lmaxminddb`. Note the extra -L in front of the directory name.